ASP.NET Core 7.0 ConfirmEmailAsync returning invalid token even though tokens are the same
I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0 app that is using Identity.
My confirm email registration ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code) is returning "Invalid token" even though the codes are the same.
My register user code is:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
     returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
     ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var user = CreateUser();

         await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
         var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
         var role = _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.UserRole).Result;

         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
             _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

             var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);

             var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
             code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

             var setTwoFactorResult = await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);

             if (!setTwoFactorResult.Succeeded)
             {
                 _logger.LogInformation("Two factor authentication failed to set.");
             }

             var addToRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);

             if (addToRoleResult.Succeeded)
             {
                 _logger.LogInformation("Role not assigned to user");
             }

             var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                 "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                 pageHandler: null,
                 values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                 protocol: Request.Scheme);

             var confirmationEmail = new EmailInfo()
             {
                 EmailTo = Input.Email,
                 Subject = "Yellow Fever Account Confirmation Email",
                 Body = $"Please use the following code to confirm your account <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>"
             };

             await _emailService.SendEmailAsync(confirmationEmail);

             return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
         }

         foreach (var error in result.Errors)
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
         }
     }

     ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
     ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
     IEnumerable<IdentityRole> roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
     ViewData["RoleId"] = new SelectList(roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

     // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
     return Page();
}

Uses
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

Produces the codes:
CfDJ8FNks8CAUJNIsn8pN7Swz8rMuOoUpyFX3t/5GlQksYR6ojIwg72q9RpktG5uY5IiDSVVSPHvADYUZys58sIVZyxe51vFle5R7ORk7Ehp92htoQtzuSboD9PJR/8dZzUD+Fx5E72FJ5snRn7hFgGcjSAw6GE2G7QK9/lZQi2cZ7nf8nY7sLbAPXDw2/z7v6k6p1tnLvLLkmom+mh5vCkiO0sjYhcWp2oPMPU5CNd5wp1zUiAY76Z+4zG328xmgB49Jw==

And once encoded:
Q2ZESjhGTmtzOENBVUpOSXNuOHBON1N3ejhyTXVPb1VweUZYM3QvNUdsUWtzWVI2b2pJd2c3MnE5UnBrdEc1dVk1SWlEU1ZWU1BIdkFEWVVaeXM1OHNJVlp5eGU1MXZGbGU1UjdPUms3RWhwOTJodG9RdHp1U2JvRDlQSlIvOGRaelVEK0Z4NUU3MkZKNXNuUm43aEZnR2NqU0F3NkdFMkc3UUs5L2xaUWkyY1o3bmY4blk3c0xiQVBYRHcyL3o3djZrNnAxdG5MdkxMa21vbSttaDV2Q2tpTzBzalloY1dwMm9QTVBVNUNOZDV3cDF6VWlBWTc2Wis0ekczMjh4bWdCNDlKdz09

When the confirm email method:
/// </summary>
[TempData]
public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
    }

    code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            "/Account/Login",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { area = "Identity" },
            protocol: Request.Scheme);

    var SuccessMessage = $"Thank you for confirming your email. You can now <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>login to the Yellow Fever Portal</a>.";

    var FailureMessage = "There was an error confirming your email. Please contact the administrator on 0141-300-1137 or email <a href='mailto: phs.yellowfever @phs.scot'>phs.yellowfever@phs.scot</a> to report this issue.";

    StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? SuccessMessage : FailureMessage;
    return Page();
}

using:
code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

The code passed in is:
Q2ZESjhGTmtzOENBVUpOSXNuOHBON1N3ejhyTXVPb1VweUZYM3QvNUdsUWtzWVI2b2pJd2c3MnE5UnBrdEc1dVk1SWlEU1ZWU1BIdkFEWVVaeXM1OHNJVlp5eGU1MXZGbGU1UjdPUms3RWhwOTJodG9RdHp1U2JvRDlQSlIvOGRaelVEK0Z4NUU3MkZKNXNuUm43aEZnR2NqU0F3NkdFMkc3UUs5L2xaUWkyY1o3bmY4blk3c0xiQVBYRHcyL3o3djZrNnAxdG5MdkxMa21vbSttaDV2Q2tpTzBzalloY1dwMm9QTVBVNUNOZDV3cDF6VWlBWTc2Wis0ekczMjh4bWdCNDlKdz09

and once decoded, it's:
CfDJ8FNks8CAUJNIsn8pN7Swz8rMuOoUpyFX3t/5GlQksYR6ojIwg72q9RpktG5uY5IiDSVVSPHvADYUZys58sIVZyxe51vFle5R7ORk7Ehp92htoQtzuSboD9PJR/8dZzUD+Fx5E72FJ5snRn7hFgGcjSAw6GE2G7QK9/lZQi2cZ7nf8nY7sLbAPXDw2/z7v6k6p1tnLvLLkmom+mh5vCkiO0sjYhcWp2oPMPU5CNd5wp1zUiAY76Z+4zG328xmgB49Jw==

The same as above.
But the ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code) returns invalid token.
Why?
Banging my head against a wall!
Help.

Here var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); in user what you are passing? userId or email? What configuration you have set here in opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;?

user is an object, it has the email address and the user id.  I also have  `services.Configure(options =>
{
options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
 options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

 options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(36500);
 options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
 options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

});`
